# Controlling media rewind/forward with keyboard shortcuts

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

I would like to control media in chrome using shortcuts, more specifically I would like to be able to rewind/forward 3 seconds in the media using a keyboard shortcut even if I'm currently inside another program. I'm using mac which lets me control start/stop globally with a hotkey but I have been unable to find a solution for forward/rewind.

Edit:
To be even more specific. I would like to be able to rewind youtube videos and udemy videos using just a hotkey while I'm working in an IDE. So let's say I'm writing in an IDE while listening to a video about programming running on udemy or youtube, at this point I can use a hotkey to pause and start the video even though I am working in the IDE. But I would also like to rewind 3 seconds with just a hotkey if there was something I need to hear again, but I don't want to have to manually switch to the browser and then use a hotkey to rewind the video, I want to do be able to do it with just one action.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It will depend on a) the media type & b) its ability to be scripted. By default, all control goes to the front-most window of the front-most app.

Comment: *"I would like to control media in chrome using shortcuts"* - A big problem here is embedded media players themselves. Not all of them have the same control options.

Answer (score 0):

You're right: the keybaord's 3 buttons of ◀︎◀︎ ▶︎ ▶︎▶︎ are able to access whatever media player was last active (in your case YT, inside the browser) regardless of whatever is the currently-active app. The controls to fast-fw/rw should be equally accessible. For example <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> to fast fwd.

Have you tried [Keyboard Maestro](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/)? Bit clunky, but considering you're trying to access controls of an object inside a browser window, you may be able to program a macro that does that specifically. May be worth asking in their forum, they're very active.